# How to find the probability of 1 of 3 bridges collapsing?

Tags: probability

Can't seem to figure out the math for this..

If the Elder bridge has a 15% chance of collapse, the Younger bridge has a 5% chance of collapse, and the Ancient bridge has a 21% chance of collapse. What is the probability that exactly one of these bridges will collapse in the next year?

Please show the math!

Comment: So what are the different events that would make it true that exactly one of the 3 bridges collapses?

Comment: @Bram28 There were no specific events given in the question.

Comment: OK, but I was asking more conceptually for now: can you describe in English what it would take for there to be exactly 1 bridge to collapse?

Comment: All three bridges were probably built by the same low bidder, so the probabilities are probably not independent.

Comment: @martycohen With that high of a chance of collapsing within a year, you're probably right!

Comment: What Bram28 was asking for was to say one bridge collapses *and the other two don't*.  That is the key to calculating the probability.  That is the key to Opt's solution, but if you can't translate the English you can't do the math on the proper computation.

Answer (score 1):

The chance of (say) the Elder bridge collapsing is $15$% ($0.15$ probability = $E_C$), and the chance of it **not** collapsing, $E_{NC}$, is the only other possiblity so $E_{NC} = 1-0.15 = 0.85$ probability, 85%.

So if you similarly find $Y_{NC}$ and $A_{NC}$ from the given percentages for $Y_C$ and $A_C$, you can calculate the chance of the *only* the Elder bridge collapsing as $E_C \times Y_{NC} \times A_{NC}$. These are probabilities, so values between $0$ and $1$, that are being multiplied here.

Then when you have calculated each of those, the probability that only the Elder, only the Youger, and only the Ancient bridge collapse respectively, you can add these possibilities together, since they do not overlap, and you have your result.

$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Name} & K & \% & K_C & K_{NC} & \text{only }K = K_C \times L_{NC} \times M_{NC} \\ \hline
\text{Elder} & E & 15 & 0.15 & 0.85 & \\
\text{Younger} & Y & 5 & & & \\
\text{Ancient} & A & 21 & & & \\ \hline
& & & & \text{Total} &
\end{array}$

Answer (score 0):

As the events are independet, we can calculate the probability as follows $$Pr\,(\text{exactly one bridge collapses}) = 0.15 (1-0.05) (1-0.21) \\+ 0.05 (1-0.15) (1-0.21) \\+ 0.21 (1-0.05) (1-0.15);$$